# Get Selected Radio Button in Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, web, sinatra, erb

I am trying to get information on which radio button is selected in the same ERB file that it is selected in.

I have an array that will always have 3 items in it. I run through that array and add them as radio buttons in the following code:

```
<% my_array.each do |item| %>
  <input type="radio" id="<%=item%>" name="selected_item" value="<%=item%>">
    <label for="<%=item%>"><%=item%></label>
<% end %>
```

Then a few lines lower I am trying to access the selected item with the following code:

```
<%= "TEST: #{selected_item}" %>
```

But it always bombs out with the following error message:

```
2016-05-04 23:51:24 - NameError - undefined local variable or method `selected_item'>
```

Any help on why it can't seem to find the radio button would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

selected_item isn't a variable or method, so your string interpolation there isn't working properly. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but all 3 of the radio buttons you're adding will have the name "selected_item".

Comment: So I used a similar workflow earlier in the project. But now I see that I had setup the local variable in the web.rb file.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the "checked" radio button's value. Thoughts on how I can do that?

Comment: Are you trying to have some code execute every time a new radio button is checked? Usually you would deal with which one is checked in a post route or something but if you aren't sending anything to a route then you might have to use javascript to solve this.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: I'm not all that comfortable with javascript yet so I couldn't really help there.